# suggestion in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

in eclipse when I write something wrong it gives me some suggestion. but in android studio I cant see this option.
for example in eclipse when I write this:

```
        ImageView  image=  findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

I gives me suggestion for casting to imagview but in android studio I don't see such an option.
should I set or change something to make it works?

when I place pointer above it:

[image]

Comment: when writing it will show you red line under that line. Press Alt+Enter and it will show you suggestion to typecast

Comment: in my android studio i see it red underlined. with the "required ImageView, found View" annotation. I don't know why you are not getting it..

Comment: there is an option in android studio  setting which will allow you to use eclipse shortcuts.Go to Settings->Keymap.

Comment: I want to have that pop up that was in eclipse. is it exists here too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In studio you can do very simple way go to widget that you declare.Automatically one popup will appear when you click on declaration line.You can directly cast that widget.
See in below image.

thankyou 
Hope this will help you.

[image]

Comment: I place mouse over it but it shows me different options. you can see in my edit.

Comment: yes right, You need to place cursor before semicolon then on left corner  red icon will shown.Just click on that icon and option will appear

Answer (score 2):

use **Ctrl + space** for suggestion and when it shows error then you want to check error then try **Alt + enter**

Answer (score 1):

**Alt+Enter** and then simply **Enter**.